# _vsnwprintf_s not working as desired

Tags: c

Writing a module to convert the unnamed argument list to string
output is not as desired.

```
void FormatOutput(wchar_t* formatstring, ...)
{
    wchar_t buffer[1024];
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    size_t size = lstrlenW(formatstring);
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, formatstring);
    size = _vsnwprintf_s(buffer, _countof(buffer), _TRUNCATE, formatstring, args);
    buffer[size] = L'\0';
    if (size < 0)
        __debugbreak();
    printf("size: %d, buff: %ls\n", size, buffer);
}
```

Invoking the module as below

```
FormatOutput(L"%s %d %d %f %c", "34", 23,34,10.23,'c');
```

Output:

```
size: 19, buff :
```

What is missing in the implementation ?

Comment: Which compiler/library ?

Comment: @Matt Correction in parameters format fixed the issue. I am using VS2013.

Comment: BTW why are you initializing `size` to `lstrlenW(formatstring)`? The initial value does not appear to be used.

Comment: May be I tried it in place of _TRUNCATE. Looks it is redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `%s` format and sending a single-byte character string argument in your call to `FormatOutput` and then to `_vsnwprintf_s`. Being a wide-character function, `_vsnwprintf_s` treats `%s` as synonymous to `%ls` and expects a wide string argument.

To resolve the issue, switch to [the `%hs` format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6.aspx), or pass the wide string literal `L"34"`. The same goes for `%c` and `c`, where you need to use `%hc` or pass `L'c'` as argument.

Answer (score 0):

The required change is to use `L"34"` while invoking the module

```
FormatOutput(L"%s %d %d %f %c", L"34", 23,34,10.23,'c');
```

Output

```
size: 20, buff: 34 23 34 10.230000 c
```